# Control OSM map in QML qt

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am trying to control the map in Qt however I keep ending up with the following error:

```
QGeoTileRequestManager: Failed to fetch tile (291271,152514,19) 5 times, giving up. Last error message was: 'Permission denied'
```

I have functions in C++ that parse the messages and calculates the position:

Map.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.14
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtLocation 5.6
import QtPositioning 5.6
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12
import Qt.labs.location 1.0

Page {
    id: mainWindow
    visible: true

    function addMarker(latitude, longitude)
    {
        var Component = Qt.createComponent("qrc:/Marker.qml")
        var item = Component.createObject(window, {
                                              coordinate: QtPositioning.coordinate(latitude, longitude)
                                          })
        map.addMapItem(item)
    }

    Map {
        id: map
        width: mainWindow.width
        height: mainWindow.height
        plugin: mapPlugin
        center: QtPositioning.coordinate(59.91, 10.75)
        Component.onCompleted: addMarker(59.91, 10.75)
        zoomLevel: 60

    }

    Plugin {
        id: mapPlugin
        name: "osm" // "mapboxgl", "esri", ...
        // specify plugin parameters if necessary
        PluginParameter {
            name: "osm.mapping.providersrepository.disabled"
            value: "true"
        }
        PluginParameter {
            name: "osm.mapping.providersrepository.address"
            value: "http://maps-redirect.qt.io/osm/5.6/"
        }
    }
}
```

Setting the coordinates is done through Q_PROPERTY:

```
#include <QObject>

class Data : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT;
    Q_PROPERTY(double gnss_log READ gnss_long WRITE set_gnss_long NOTIFY gnss_long_changed);
    Q_PROPERTY(double gnss_lat READ gnss_lat WRITE set_gnss_lat NOTIFY gnss_lat_changed);
public: signals:

    void gnss_long_changed();
    void gnss_lat_changed();

public slots:

    void set_gnss_long(double);
    void set_gnss_lat(double);

public:
    Data();

    double gnss_long();
    double gnss_lat();

private:
    double m_gnss_long;
    double m_gnss_lat;
};


void Data::set_gnss_long(double curr_long)
{
    // Checks whether updated baud rate changed
    if (curr_long == m_gnss_long)
        return;

    m_gnss_long = curr_long;
    qDebug() << m_gnss_long;
    //Emits signal indicating change
    emit gnss_long_changed();
}

double Data::gnss_long()
{
    return m_gnss_long;
}
```

I when I run this, I get a blank screen with a bunch of the errors mentioned above.

Comment: please provide a [mre]. what is the values of lattitude and longitude

Comment: I added a reproducible example, the coordinate changes over a set interval

Comment: But to what value (or range of values does it change)? What is the version of Qt you use?

Comment: Qt 5.15 and I need them to be from -180 to 180.

Comment: The latitude must be in the range of -90 to 90, and the longitude between -180 to 180, have you met that requirement?

Comment: Yeah I have. I only posted the longitude code.

Comment: In the .qml you provide you don't use "Data", do you still get the black screen on the map?

Comment: I do use Data, I created an instance of Data thats calleed data_out in main.

Comment: My intention with the question is to know if "Data" generates the black screen. In your current code in the .qml there is no about Data. Also whar is "window"?. I have implemented that code and I have not had problems so the error is probably another so in return I ask you to provide a real MRE.

Comment: What you want to implement I have done many times, for example you can check the following posts: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A6622587+map+%5Bqml%5D+%5Bc%2B%2B%5D

Comment: The thing is that I want it to be actively updated like every second or so. What you did was do it with a button.

Comment: Please provide a [mre], show the main.cpp and other neccesary class

Comment: Since you do not provide a full MRE I will show you a demo in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since the OP has not provided an MRE my answer will only show a demo. The logic is to create a QProperty that exposes the position, then a binding must be done:

```cpp
#include <QGeoCoordinate>
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QTimer>

#include <random>

class Data: public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QGeoCoordinate gnssPosition READ gnssPosition WRITE setGnssPosition NOTIFY gnssPositionChanged)
public:
    const QGeoCoordinate &gnssPosition() const{
        return m_gnssPosition;
    }
    void setGnssLatitude(qreal latitude){
        QGeoCoordinate coordinate(latitude, m_gnssPosition.longitude());
        setGnssPosition(coordinate);
    }
    void setGnssLongitude(qreal longitude){
        QGeoCoordinate coordinate(m_gnssPosition.latitude(), longitude);
        setGnssPosition(coordinate);
    }
    void setGnssPosition(const QGeoCoordinate &newGnssPosition){
        if (m_gnssPosition == newGnssPosition)
            return;
        m_gnssPosition = newGnssPosition;
        emit gnssPositionChanged();
    }
signals:
    void gnssPositionChanged();
private:
    QGeoCoordinate m_gnssPosition;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#if QT_VERSION < QT_VERSION_CHECK(6, 0, 0)
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
#endif

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    Data data_out;
    data_out.setGnssPosition(QGeoCoordinate(59.91273, 10.74609));

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("data_out", &data_out);
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    QTimer timer;
    timer.setInterval(1000);
    QObject::connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, &data_out, [&data_out](){
        std::random_device rd;
        std::mt19937 e2(rd());
        std::uniform_real_distribution<> dist(-.05, .05);

        QGeoCoordinate coord = data_out.gnssPosition();
        coord.setLatitude(coord.latitude() + dist(e2));
        coord.setLongitude(coord.longitude() + dist(e2));
        data_out.setGnssPosition(coord);
        // qDebug() << data_out.gnssPosition();
    });
    timer.start();

    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtLocation 5.15
import QtPositioning 5.15

Window {
    id: mainWindow
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    property Component markerProvider: MapQuickItem {
        anchorPoint.x: rect.width / 2
        anchorPoint.y: rect.height / 2
        sourceItem: Rectangle{
            id: rect
            width: 40
            height: 40
            color: "salmon"
        }
    }

    function addMarker(coordinate){
        var marker = markerProvider.createObject()
        console.log(marker)
        marker.coordinate = coordinate
        map.addMapItem(marker)
    }

    Map {
        id: map
        width: mainWindow.width
        height: mainWindow.height
        plugin: mapPlugin
        center: data_out.gnssPosition
        zoomLevel: 12

    }

    Plugin {
        id: mapPlugin
        name: "osm" // "mapboxgl", "esri", ...
        // specify plugin parameters if necessary
        PluginParameter {
            name: "osm.mapping.providersrepository.disabled"
            value: "true"
        }
        PluginParameter {
            name: "osm.mapping.providersrepository.address"
            value: "http://maps-redirect.qt.io/osm/5.6/"
        }
    }
    Connections{
        target: data_out
        function onGnssPositionChanged(){
            addMarker(data_out.gnssPosition)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there no way to trigger a change in the coordinates through a signal from ```gnssPositionChanged``` instead of timing it?

Comment: So if I were to create a ```QObject::connect(&data_out, &Data::gnssPositionChanged, &data_out, [&data_out](){QGeoCoordinate coord = data_out.gnssPosition(); data_out.setGnssPosition(coord); });``` and set the latitude and longitude internal through the setters, that should work?

Comment: I do understand what the code does but I'm trying to find a way to merge it with my current code. I have a parser that sets the longtitude and latitude in another class, I have replaced the functions I had with ```data_out.setGnssLongitude(Parser::get_gnss_longitude(data));``` and ```data_out.setGnssLatitude(Parser::get_gnss_latitude(data));```. That means that the signal ```gnssPositionChanged``` is emitted everytime that position is updated. However, the location does not change as the signal is emitted hence why I am asking for your opinion on whether a connection is required.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237067/discussion-between-unity123-and-eyllanesc).

Comment: I understand but the code base I work with is huge and I simply can't minimize it.

Comment: The problem I'm facing is the input to those setter functions are being received however when i qDebug the actual coordinate, it would output the following: QGeoCoordinate(?, ?). The inputs to the setters are just doubles, nothing more than that, theres no other magic but because of that output, the setGnssPosition is never called.

Comment: Do you know why those setters that you provided do not read my double inputs?

Comment: I'm getting an output of false nan nan. Eventhough inputs are normal.

Comment: I fixed the issue of getting an invalid coordinate. I had to just initialize the coordinate ```data_out.setGnssPosition(QGeoCoordinate(59.91273, 10.74609));``` within the class constructor. However, the map is not changing its center now even though the coordinates are being read properly.

Comment: Coordinates are being parsed into a suitable format and the signal is being emitted. Why is it that the map is not being centered? The only thing I have changed from your code is put the initial coordinate in the constructor and to set the data within my own parser which are read directly in the ```setGnssPosition``` function.

Comment: Am I supposed to call setGnssPostion somewhere else?

Comment: Sincerely I got tired, bye

Comment: It makes no sense how the map isnt being recentered. I double checked the QML as well as the output to see if it is correct.

Comment: Is it possible if you could take a look at my code in chat? @eyllanesc